# How can I get a proto file to reference a message defined in another proto?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am working with a gRPC service project that was generated by Visual Studio. I have two proto files located in the same "Protos" directory. I have one proto the has an import for the other proto file. It appears to find the file but I am not able to reference any of the messages from the other. When I do I get a "blahblah" is not defined error. I have taken some screenshots of the situation. Any help would be very much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in different `package` spaces; try `thing.ThingRequest`, or `.thing.ThingRequest` (the leading `.` means "absolute", like a uri starting with `/`)

Comment: That worked! This was driving me crazy!